# asp.net mvc dynamic regular expression variable

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

i am dynamically validating regular expression in which the regular expression are from database

ok so the thing is happening that `\` is replaced by `\\` **`which is not validating the email`**

i have  `Regex RegExp = new Regex("@" + IsMandatoryTextTextAreaFiles.vcr_RegularExpression, RegexOptions.Compiled);`

in which  `IsMandatoryTextTextAreaFiles.vcr_RegularExpression=\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*` .

So what to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `\` are not replaced by `\\`, my guess is that you are looking at the value in the debugger, where the string is displayed as it would be written as a string literal in the code.

Concatenating the string `"@"` and some other string doesn't make it a literal string, i.e. `"@" + "asdf"` is not the same as `@"asdf"`, it's just `"@asdf"`. That means that the `@` becomes part of the pattern. Just use the string as it is:

```
Regex RegExp = new Regex(IsMandatoryTextTextAreaFiles.vcr_RegularExpression, RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Note that the regular expression is only verifying that a string *contains* a valid email, not that it *is only* a valid email. So for example the string `"Here: asdf@asdf.com dear sir"` would pass the test.

You can use `^` and `$` to specify the beginning and end of the string in the regular expression:

```
^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$
```